# Nextcord send a message to a specific channel (discord.py fork)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

So, I've been trying to make a suggestion discord bot, so it sends a message to a specific channel when prompted and verified with a button, but I can't seem to make it work.
My code is here:

```py
import nextcord
import os
import requests
import asyncio
import random
import catapi
import json
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()
apicat = catapi.CatApi(api_key=os.environ['CAT_API_KEY'])
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)
colors = [0x00ffee,0x32a852,0x4287f5,0xcc2af5,0xf7e7a6,0xdea4a2]

def run_coro(coroutine):
  return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)



class YesOrNo(nextcord.ui.View):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = None
    
  @nextcord.ui.button(emoji="✔", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.success) 
  async def yes(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):
    
    channel = client.get_channel(950111018405748746)
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Suggestion was sent!", color=0x51ff00)
    await channel.send("test")
    await interaction.edit(embed=embed, view=None)
    self.value = True 
    self.stop()

  @nextcord.ui.button(emoji="✖️", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.danger) 
  async def no(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):

    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Suggestion was discarded!", color=0xff0000)
    
    await interaction.edit(embed=embed, view=None)
    self.value = False
    self.stop()
```

But I receive this error:
AttributeError: 'YesOrNo' object has no attribute 'client'
Any ideas how to fix it?
I've tried changing all the clients and stuff to bot, I've tried putting client inside the init, super init, class, ui.button, async def, and I STILL DO NOT KNOW WHAT'S WRONG!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to include the full traceback of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `client` and then define it with `self.client`, like this:

```py
class YesOrNo(nextcord.ui.View):


#pass `client` here
               ↓
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = None
    self.client = client    # ← then define self.client
```

Your code will look like this:

```py
class YesOrNo(nextcord.ui.View):

  def __init__(client, self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = None
    self.client = client
    
  @nextcord.ui.button(emoji="✔", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.success) 
  async def yes(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):
    
    channel = client.get_channel(950111018405748746)
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Suggestion was sent!", color=0x51ff00)
    await channel.send("test")
    await interaction.edit(embed=embed, view=None)
    self.value = True 
    self.stop()

  @nextcord.ui.button(emoji="✖️", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.danger) 
  async def no(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):

    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Suggestion was discarded!", color=0xff0000)
    
    await interaction.edit(embed=embed, view=None)
    self.value = False
    self.stop()
```

> This is probably it.

• Sxviaat